# Open apps can not be activated after a while

Tags: unity, launcher

I just bought a system 76 kudu pro with Ubuntu 14.04 preinstalled. When I have a few applications open and haven't used some of them for a while and want to use them again, it won't work. The apps are still in the launcher and are visible in alt-tab but when I click on them or alt-tab to them, nothing happens. I can open this application again but then I would have to start over with my work... Does anybody know what this can be?